# How can I make a record detail page for chatter groups?

Tags: chatter, lightning-experience, chatter-groups

Create the Chatter group indicated in the requirements and customize the group record page so it displays the specified information

I have created chatter group but unble to get what does it mean by "customize the group record page so it displays the specified information"

Comment: I assume you're doing it in lightning. See at the top, for the gear icon, click it and find EDIT PAGE option. And now try to do some customization.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Tushar. Please avoid use of greetings like Hi, good morning, thanks, or regards in your questions and answers.

Comment: Your question is vague; what are you referring to when you say customizing chatter group record page? Do you have any documentation link or article to support or may be a little more details in your question would help the community in answering.

Comment: ok Mahmood. It is related to  Salesforce superbage Lightning Experience Rollout Specialist step 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means create a Lightning Record Page for the Group object.  It took me awhile to figure that out, too, as I forgot Groups applied to chatter groups.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of how you make "Lightning Record Page for the Group object"? I still don't understand how you did it.